# HATEOAS: Should the server accept the hypermedia links in request payload

Tags: web-services, rest, web-applications, hateoas, json-api

So, we have adopted similar standards as HATEOAS in implementing our restful apis. We provide links in the response to allow the client to navigate or perform certain things. Now the question is,

If the client wants to consume this response, make changes to some of the attributes of the resource and post it back to the server for an update, while not sanitizing the hypermedia links that were provided in the response. Should server accept this request payload as valid and ignore the hypermedia links in the request payload or should client be not allowed to send such a payload?

Our only concern in allowing this is that if the payload is very big and the client is only make changes to a couple attributes then there is a performance overheard but the counter argument is that the client needs to sanitize responses in order to make subsequent requests.

Can you please advice on what is the best practice?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Client should only POST data, and not metadata (hypermedia links) - this are handled by the server only. It's also not clear what do you mean by "sanitization" - the links are build by the server, the client's only duty is to consume them and handle various responses & http status codes.

Also, if you're interested in partial updates you should have a look at the [PATCH](http://williamdurand.fr/2014/02/14/please-do-not-patch-like-an-idiot/) verb.

Comment: Hi, thanks for responding. What I meant by sanitizing is that our response is very huge and has lots of hypermedia links in it. So if a client only wishes to change a couple values and post it back, should the server accept it and just ignore the hypermedia links in the request? or is the client suppose to process the whole response and remove every hypermedia or create a full request from scratch?